# How do I group a custom post type by a custom post meta field?

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type called merchandise. I am modifying it to allow me to group like products together by a "group name" - merchandise_details_group (which is a string).

The data is saving just fine, but when I try to pull the posts back and group them based up on the "group name" nothing happens. The order doesnt seem to change.

Here is what I have pulling the data:

```
$results = new WP_Query([
    "post_type" => "merchandise",
    "posts_per_page" => -1,
    "tax_query" => [[
            "taxonomy" => "merchcategory",
            "terms" => $atts['merchcategory'],
            "field" => "slug"
    ]],
    "orderby" => [
        "merchandise_details_group" => "asc"
    ]
]);
```

How do I make this work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Orderby Parameters for `WP_Query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters). The `orderby` argument should be `meta_value` or `meta_value_num` and the `order` argument should be the direction (`ASC`).

You'll also need to provide the `meta_key` argument, which is where your `merchandise_details_group` should go.

Note that the `orderby` argument should be `meta_value` if it's an alphabetical arrangement, if it's numeric, you'll want `meta_value_num`, otherwise you'll end up with some undesired results (1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, etc.)

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'merchandise',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value', // or 'meta_value_num'
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_key'       => 'merchandise_details_group',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'merchcategory',
            'terms'    => $atts['merchcategory'],
            'field'    => 'slug'
        )
    ),
);

$results = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```